# Google Chrome font will not change

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I changed the font in google chrome and then changed it back because I decided I didn't like the change. Now it will not change back.

[These are the settings I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ45l.jpg)

[Here is how font is being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNdnq.jpg)

The above screenshot shows the correct font being used in internet explorer and the wrong font being used in chrome. 
Is there anyway to reset this? I even reinstalled chrome. This has been going on for weeks.

---

I tried reinstalling and deleting appdata. Can someone please think of a way that I can make it look like chrome was never on this computer. The fonts still have not updated back to the defaults.

Comment: did you just try delete the chrome installation file manually which is located in AppData ?

Comment: I'll try that now